# jQuery autocomplete focus one more time after hide

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does anybody know why after clicking outside the search field and hiding autocomplete results a focus activate one more time? See please at http://layot.prestatrend.com/
Type for example just 3 letters at search field 'ipo'. Thanks for any reply!

Comment: Can you include relevant code in your question? Then the answers will be more useful for future visitors.

Comment: But it is a java-script file.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is just the behavior of the plugin to re-focus the input if the suggestion menu was visible.

When you click outside (or use TAB to unfocus) the input, the "blur" event is triggered:

```
.blur(function() {
    hasFocus = 0;
    if (!config.mouseDownOnSelect) {
        hideResults();
    }
})
```

Executing `hideResults' executes another function`hideResultsNow` which makes this check:

```
var wasVisible = select.visible();
...
if (wasVisible)
    // position cursor at end of input field
    $.Autocompleter.Selection(input, input.value.length, input.value.length);
```

`wasVisible` is true because the suggestion menu is open.

The job of `$.Autocompleter.Selection` is to set the text selection in the input and at the end, it focuses the input:

```
$.Autocompleter.Selection = function(field, start, end) {
    if (field.createTextRange) {
        ...
    } else if (field.setSelectionRange) {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
    field.focus();
};
```

If you click again outside the input, the variable `wasVisible` is false, because the suggestion menu is not open anymore, and the `$.Autocompleter.Selection` is not executed so the input is not re-focused.

Comment: So how to make remove this re-focus behavior?

Comment: That I don't know. Are you sure you are using the latest version of the plugin ? Difficult to help you without know what plugin you are using exactly.

Comment: No, it is not latest cause it is a part of CMS Prestahop. Version is Autocomplete - jQuery plugin 1.0.2, Copyright (c) 2007 Dylan Verheul, Dan G. Switzer, Anjesh Tuladhar, Jörn Zaefferer

Comment: Cannot really help you further then. If you can, use another autocomplete plugin.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found: Destroy the autocomplete on focus event for re initializing it.

```
function defaultFocusAction(e, options) {
  if($(e.currentTarget).val() == '') {
    $(e.currentTarget).autocomplete('destroy');
    $(e.currentTarget).autocomplete(options);
  }
  $(e.currentTarget).trigger('keydown.autocomplete');
}
var options = {
  autoFocus : false,
  delay : 0,
  minLength: 0,
  source: ['foo', 'bar']
};
$('input.autocomplete').autocomplete(options).focus(function(e) {
  defaultFocusAction(e, options);
});
```